# Integrating Cloudfoundry UAA with external identity provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp, cloudfoundry-uaa

We have all the user data in our local mysql database. We are moving our services to cloud and I need to use cloudfoundry UAA to authenticate by calling a login microservice endpoint on our network instead of doing uaac add user for all the users in db.

I am new to this, it would help me if you can explain the steps to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume (based on the SAML tags on your question) that you are thinking of doing this with SAML. If this is your first time doing SAML then there is a bit of learning curve. If so you may find it easier to just creating a custom Login app.

**SAML**

You would setup an Identity Provider and the IdP would authenticate users against either mysql or your login microservice. `simplesamlphp` can be used for this purpose. A user would authenticate to the IDP, the IdP generates a SAML assertion (e.g a signed xml doc with information about the user) that gets sent to the Service Provider (UAA). The service provider then looks at the assertion to determine who the user is. `UAA` supports SAML logins. It has been a while since I've set it up that way, but I recall you run a separate 'login' war from the rest of UAA, and the login war uses APIs to talk to UAA. You also need to configure the SAML trust relationship between `ssp` and the UAA login war. This isn't hard to do if you are familiar with SAML. If you aren't then it can be difficult to get all the pieces right.

**Custom Login App**
I think an easier approach is to just build your own login app that calls your authentication service and the UAA apis. UAA provides a [sample app](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/tree/master/samples/login) and [documentation](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/login/Login-APIs.md)